# ffmpeg http slower than downloading first

Tags: ffmpeg

When trying to get a clip of a video from a remote source
Input source:
`ffprobe version 3.3.2-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'http://website.com/video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-07-13T15:44:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:57:32.42, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1939 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv), 720x480 [SAR 10:11 DAR 15:11], 1745 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29970 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-07-13T15:44:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-07-13T15:44:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler`

Current command:
ffmpeg version 3.3.2-static
`ffmpeg.linux -threads 2 -y -ss 3273 -i "http://website.com/video.mp4" -an -movflags +faststart -preset veryfast -codec copy /outputfolder/trimmed_video.mp4`
This 5m35.102s to create a 45mb 2min file.

If I download the file using `wget` it takes 28s and using ffmpeg only takes 0.243s

If I add `-vn` OR `-an` to the output portion of the command it completes the trim in about 2.101s. Meaning it's faster to download the two stream and merge them myself.

Can anyone explain this behaviour and why my first command takes so long when on a lot of other video files it's very fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Videos where the command completed fast were optimized for streaming by youtube.
User uploaded media was not optimized.
Running ffmpeg with `-movflags +faststart` on the files fixed the issues server side.